# fork steerer compatability

Tags: mountain-bike

a 1 1/8” Aluminum, 1.5 Taper Steerer will it fit on my frame?
 My frame is gt chucker 3.0 26er and the fork is manitou minute 26er [enter image description here][1]

[image]

Comment: MY FORK IS MANITOU MINUTE 26ER PLS HELP IM ABOUT TO BUY IT IM SCARED IF IT WILL NOT BE COMPATIBLE PLS

Comment: From what I've seen on the web, it looks like a straight 1 1/8 head tube so a tapered 1.5" steerer won't fit.

Comment: nooooo </3 :( :(

Answer (score 1):

If your headtube is 34mm in diameter then only EC34 Headset can fit in.
This means that you can only go as much as 1-1/8 inch fork.

Unfortunately there is no conversion kit that I have heard of for adapting 34mm headtube to 1.5 inch steerer.

If your headtube is larger than 34 mm, you might have a chance. Take a look at this doc: http://www.hopetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/HOPEHEADSETS2011Web.pdf

[image]

Comment: From what I can see the GT Chucker has a 1 1/8" head tube, so a conversion kit won't work - correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: you are right, I've made a mistake myself.